# variable or field 'insertion_sort' declared void line 13 column 27

Tags: c++, sorting, insertion-sort

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std ;

void insertion_sort ( int ch[] );

int size = 7 , i , j , k , l , temp , place ;

int main () { 

        int ch [] = { 2,6,4,75,3,4,4};

        void insertion_sort (ch ) ;

        for ( l = 0 ; l < size ; ++l )
        cout<<ch[l]<<" ";       

}


void insertion_sort ( int c [] ){ 

        for ( i = 0 ; i < size ; ++i){

            k=i;

                if ( c[i+1]<c[i] ){

                    temp = c[i+1];
                    c[i+1]=c[i];
                    c[i]=temp;
                }

            while ( k >=0  ){

                if( c[k]<c[k-1] )
                {
                    place=c[k-1];
                    c[k-1]=c[k];
                    c[k]=place;

                }


                --k;
            }



        }   
}
```

Comment: that `void` in front of a function call seems completely unnecessary

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you understand the three different ways to see a function:

1. *Declaration* of the function:

   void insertion_sort( int ch[] );
2. *Definition* of the function:

   void insertion_sort( int ch[] ) {
      // your code
   }
3. *Call* to the function, like this, inside `main()`:

   insertion_sort(ch);

---

Check my example with [Quicksort (C++)](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/quicksort-c/), it's really relevant!

Answer (score 0):

`void insertion_sort (ch ) ;` doesn't make sense. It means declare a variable named `insertion_sort` with type `void` and initialized by `ch`. If you just want to call the function change it to

```
insertion_sort(ch);
```